# Повторное открытие активити

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста если попеременно открыть первую активность, затем вторую активность и снова первую, таким методом как указано ниже, она восстановится из режима onPause()/onStop(), или будет создана заново?

Дело в том что мне показалось что активность создаётся заново, и я начал искать решение данного вопроса, после прочтения литературы, закралось сомнение по данному убеждению. Также решение данной задачи схоже на множественные костыли, нежели чем на реальное решение.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.activity_one) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);

        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.activity_two) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);

        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.activity_tree) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class);

        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: существование активити, которая не находится на переднем плане (не видима на экране) никак не гарантировано системой, поэтому вы должны предпринимать меры по сохранению состояния при любом уходе в фон. В чем вы видите костыли в вашем примере кода?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще система может убить Активити в любой момент (если ей понадобится память) так что гарантий нет. Но в принципе при возврате, Активити восстанавливается.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но здесь у Вас ключевое слово "возврате", а вопрос состоит в использовании команды startActivity(...), при повторном её использовании, окно (не уничтоженное системой) восстановится или запустится ещё одно?

Comment: по умолчанию в Taks'e создается новая Активити, можно добавлять разные флаги, которые скажут системе как себя вести.

Comment: Вот https://habrahabr.ru/post/186434/ почитайте про такс

Answer (score 1):

Используйте логи в методах цикла жизни активити,чтобы отследить как она себя ведет. Мне в свое время очень помогло.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause " );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStop ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy ");
    }
```